# Samsung Galaxy S4: what application is responsible for "Time to home" notices?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, services, location-services

On my Samsung Galaxy S4, I constantly get notifications "Time to home XXX minutes". They are not only useless for me, but also apparently some app is accessing my location, internet, and is draining my battery.

I couldn't find out what is responsible for that. What app is showing that messages, and how to turn it off?

Comment: as they already answered it is google now, regarding your battery drain I think it is unlikely this is the one causing the problem, UNLESS you have your gps set to HIGH accuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Now, you can disable in the settings of the "Search" app.